# Mesos Kafka: Task uses more resources than available

Tags: apache-kafka, mesos, marathon

I'm trying to launch Kafka on mesos (using Mesosphere Package), the scheduler is launched without any problem, it receives some offers and accepts, then it fails with the following error:

> message: "Task uses more resources cpus(kafka, kafka-principal, {resource_id: 839353ba-b183-400f-a529-eed53a0e7385}):1; mem(kafka, kafka-principal, {resource_id: 8a027d22-4f00-4148-9489-fe3934cb296f}):1000; ports(kafka, kafka-principal, {resource_id: c16183e5-0f23-4fd8-9335-1ccc018dc0bd}):[9092-9092]; cpus(kafka, kafka-principal, {resource_id: 98a75b3f-b242-47a7-8bf5-eaf9ea14609a}):0.5; mem(kafka, kafka-principal, {resource_id: 32b57d25-d0e8-47c0-b77d-8e3019962925}):256 than available ports(kafka):[1025-2180, 2182-3887, 3889-5049, 5052-8079, 8082-8180, 8182-32000]; cpus(kafka):2; mem(kafka):2415; disk(*):64283"

Comparing the requested resources and the ones available I can't see what is the problem. 
Does anyone understand what is the problem, and if so, how to fix it?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please open an issue at https://github.com/mesos/kafka/issues, this looks like a bug

Comment: I think there's already one like yours - https://github.com/mesos/kafka/issues/226